# Does adding business logic in a view model in asp.net increase the size of the object being passed to the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optimization, view, viewmodel

This is something I've been trying to find definitive answers on and have found no luck online thus far.  If in an ASP.NET project I have a view model that I'm using to pass data to the view in the browser, does including methods for accessing the model layer to fetch data increase the actual size of the resulting object being passed?  My intuition is saying yes and I've been trying to read through other answers on stack overflow to find a solid answer to support it, but have had no luck.

The view model has some truly monolithic methods in it, some of them spanning 100+ lines or more going through LINQ operations to filter enumerable lists of data.

Comment: You are passing your view to the browser in the form of generated html. Adding business logic to your viewmodel does not affect the size of the html. Your view (which is a dynamically generated class) lives only on the server.

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo!  JosephRT explained it a bit further so it seems the issue is largely coupling in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, it shouldn't.  A view is (typically) built from your Razor .cshtml and sent to the user.  Only the contents of your view (the layout, bundled JS, stylesheets, page itself, etc) are sent to the user.  The ViewModel is only used in building the view.

MVC has a concept called [model binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding), which is where incoming HTTP request's data is mapped to an appropriate set of parameters.  On a request a new ViewModel will be created and passed to the appropriate Action method (or if the request can be mapped to a set of parameters, that also happens; doesn't have to be a single parameter).

On a side note, having a complicated ViewModel can make model binding hard.  And having business logic in the ViewModel is also frowned upon; that makes it harder to reuse and follow.  It's ideal to move it out into your business layer, or barring that into your controller.

Comment: Thanks for the help with this.  I was looking around for this information in specific and was surprised how I didn't run into something.  In this case it's   more of a web form done in an MVC fashion, rather than razor.  I wish it was done in razor, but that is a different matter.